# Tabulate count of recurring values from a column onto a table new sheet

Tags: excel, vba, count

Status where I pick up the values:

[image: Status where I pick up the values]

as you can see with the 5 I want the values on the status to generate to that sheet numerically:

[image: as you can see with the 5 I want the values on the status to generate to that sheet numerically]

My task is to create a for loop that picks up certain values and transfer them to a new sheet counting how many errors there are in that category

Comment: in wich row should the loop start? What should happen with the "fixed" values? do you just want to count how many of each ("Closed","Rejected","Deferred","Duplicate") there are?

Comment: @user:15262984 -  Slightly off topic but a piece of advice: to capture windows screen shots, you can use `Alt-PrintScrn` for the whole screen and `WindowsKey-Shift-S` for a selected area

Answer (score 1):

if you do not have any complicated processing, I would suggest this is most simply done using worksheet function `COUNTIFS`

For this example:

[image]
The formula in e.g. `E3` is

```
=COUNTIF($B$3:$B$19, D3)
```

or if you want to set it up as a "spill" function (automatically sized output) put this ONLY in cell `E3`

```
=COUNTIF($B$3:$B$19, D3:D8)
```

If you want to do it by VBA then this is quite simple solution:

```
Option Explicit

Function get_count(ByVal value_to_count As String) As Variant
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
  
  Dim r_in As Range
  
  ' this is where my input data start - looks like on your sheet it might be c2?
  Set r_in = Range(ws.Range("B3"), ws.Range("B3").End(xlDown))
  
  get_count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r_in, value_to_count)
  

End Function
```

And the formula in cell `F2` is

```
=get_count(D3)
```